# Provision server from the ground up in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I need to provision a very fresh Ubuntu server with Ansible. At the beginning it only has `root` user and a generated password. The first action I need to do is to create a `service` user, set password to it, optionally, upload my local user's keys (so I will be able to log in without passwords) and disable `root` logins. Then I need to run a role as a `service` user. How can I do that in one playbook (e.g. signle `ansible-playbook provision.yml` instead of `ansible-playbook init.yml && ansible-playbook apply_roles.yml`)? The problem is that I need to switch users somewhere after I created `service` and then (and all future logins) I need to login as him.

Is it a good idea to configure `ansible_user` for this host as `service` and only override it once (to `root`) for initial setup? Any best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves, a Ubuntu instance starts out with a generated root user and a local user [with access to sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo):

I think the cleanest approach to this would be to install that local user's keys via bash script first, via:

```
ssh-copy-id <server>
```

( if that command is available from the command line where you run ansible )

and then go on to run your Ansible script after that line in the bash script.

( Though I think it would also possible to store the creds of the local user in an [ansible vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#variables-and-vaults) .. I haven't used the vault yet, so I'm less familiar with it. )

I would specify the service user in either a kick-off file ( as [become_user](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) ) or via ansible_user in the inventory, as you said. ( But you may run into issues with doing that according to [this older issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4688). )

If I used a kick-off file to specify the user, that file would have a role ( let's say web-server ), and that role would have a [dependency](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies) ( let's say common ).

In the common role, I would have a task that attempted a command with a known result using the service user ( that was set to [ignore errors](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html) ). If that task didn't return the expected result, I would then create the service user and copy that service user's keys to the server. Each task involved would need to override the become_user to the local user.

After that role dependency was executed, the main role(s) would follow, and all of the remaining tasks should be executed as the service user.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple plays in a single playbook. Create a play for the tasks you would like to run as root and another one for role that should run as service:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  # your tasks here

- hosts: all
  remote_user: service
  roles:
  - your_role
```